# Cannot rename a file in uno WASM Platform

Tags: uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I have a uno app where I can rename a file using uno UWP but the same code does not rename the file when build against the uno WASM platform.

I am getting the list of files in a folder using a StorageFolder object.

```
StorageFolder SourceFolder = new FolderPicker();
ObservableCollection<StorageFile> SourceFiles = new SourceFiles();
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await SourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach(StorageFile sf in files)
{
    SourceFiles.Add(sf);
}
```

SourceFiles are then bound to a ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="imagelist" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceFiles}".../>
```

At a later point in the app I have a button to rename selected items in the ListView.

The Code behind looks like this:

```
int imageNumber = 0;
foreach(var item in imageList.SelectedItems as StorageFile)
{
    imageNumber++;
    string newname=$"{imageNumber}.jpg";
    if (item is StorageFile sf)
    {
        await sf.RenameAsync(newname);
    }   
}
```

This works in UWP but in WASM it appears to hang at the RenameAsync method.  The foreach loop never progresses.

I am wondering if the IReadOnlyList is the problem in WASM but not in UWP.  Is there something that I can do differently?

Comment: Looking at StorageFile object in both UWP and WASM, WASM Uno does not implement FolderRelativeId or IsAvailable.  Does either of these affect renaming the file?  Is there a workaround?  I need to be able to rename these files in WASM.